# Compiling multiple C files having underlying functions from a common file

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I went through all StackOverflow threads regarding this but could not find one that matched my problem.
I am trying to implement different data structures (implemented in `stack.c`, `queue.c`) which get basic functions from another file `storage.c`. Here are their header files -

**storage.h**

```
typedef struct _circular_list
{
     int *array, head, tail;
     size_t size, count;
} circular_list;
typedef circular_list *clist;

clist Initialize(size_t);
clist WriteAtTail(clist, int);
int RemoveAtHead(clist);
int RemoveAtTail(clist);
clist WriteAtHead(clist, int)
```

**stack.h**

```
#include "storage.h"
#define stack clist
#define push(s, i) WriteAtTail(s, i)
int pop(stack);
int popKey(stack, int);
```

**queue.h**

```
#define queue clist
#define EnQueue(q,i) WriteAtTail(q,i)
#define DeQueue(q) RemoveAtHead(q)
```

I include them in the main C file

**driver.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"
#include "queue.h"
```

Now if i try to compile them using

`gcc -o driver driver.c storage.c stack.c queue.c`

I get an error `unknown type name 'clist'` in `queue.h`.

If I try to include `storage.h` in queue.h as well, I get an error that I have multiple declarations for the structure.

How do I go about compiling this?

Comment: You don't have any "clist" defined in your code.
You must use "circular_list", your type is defined like that

Comment: I have `typedef`ed the structure in `storage.h` to `*clist`.

Comment: then take off the *, typedef is just for the name of the type, if you want to have a "pointer to a clist", when you declare your variable you have to put the *

Comment: do not typedef struct definitions.  rather use' struct tagname' in all references to the struct.  Such typedef's clutter the code, are mis-leading (like that 'clist'), make the code less understandable, and clutter the compiler name space.  Do not use leading '_' (underscore) in names, as the compiler does the same thing, which can result in confusion (and in earlier compilers) errors in the resulting compiled code.

Comment: have a read about [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: the posted code has two different, visible definitions of 'clist'  Compiling with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at least '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic') will allow the compiler to tell you of the problems.  Please fix the warnings, then edit the posted code.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include storage.h in stack.h or queue.h you have to include it in your driver.c file before including one of the other files. Otherwise the compiler does not know about the declarations of storage.h.

A better solution is to include storage.h directly in stack.h and queue.h. To avoid getting compiler errors due to multiple declarations you have to change your storage.h like this:

```
#if !defined(INC_STORAGE_H)
#define INC_STORAGE_H

/* original storage.h contents go here */

#endif /* INC_STORAGE_H */
```

Or simply write `#pragma once` at the beginning of the storage.h if your compiler supports it. (If you're writing a library for other people to use I recommend the first solution)